# keypress method for input field validation

Tags: jquery

I was trying to do simple input field validation to restrict some special characters,I got the following solution for that.
But I am unable to understand that what is happening in this ternary operator
 `var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);`
Can anyone explain?please..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#textarea').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.!?]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("enter only valid string(123 abc , . ! ?)");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-xs-12">Reason<span class="requiredField">*</span></label> <textarea id="textarea"  rows="2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Try this solution once, https://jsfiddle.net/8shudu55/1/

Comment: `e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode` doesn't make sense - it's basically saying that if `e.charCode` is defined then *don't* use it, but if it is not defined then *do* use it - the reason it works despite this is that `e.which` will be defined. Note that the user can edit an input's value without using the keyboard, so you probably should run the same validation on the `change` event. (And don't forget to validate server-side too.)

Comment: @Mr.J your solution is accepting only numbers

Comment: @nnnnnn your are saying to change `.change` from `.keypress`  rite?

Comment: I'm not saying to *not* use `keypress`, I'm saying that `keypress` on its own isn't enough. So consider using `change` as well.

Comment: @krish Try this, now it will allow only alphabets and numbers https://jsfiddle.net/8shudu55/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode` Convert a Unicode number into a character.

`var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.!?]+$");` Its a regular expression to check if the entered key is from alphabets or numbers or full stop or a comma or a !.

`String.fromCharCode(e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);` this return either the key code of pressed key or the char code.

Ex: `var res = String.fromCharCode(65);` return A

`if (regex.test(str)) {` to check whether the key pressed is accepted or not.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to bind this character verification to more events.

- keypress
- paste

And for browser compatibility, look for the char code in all possible event attribute.

- which
- charCode
- keyCode

And I added an exception for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, as it is a `textarea` and user may want to change line.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#textarea').on("keypress paste",function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.!?]+$");
    var charCode = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
    
    if(charCode!=13){ // to allow [ENTER]
    
      var str = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
      if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        alert("enter only valid string(123 abc , . ! ?)");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="col-xs-12">Reason<span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
<textarea id="textarea"  rows="2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Right... The `change` fires with `keypress` when using `shift` key. I edited. To check on `keypress` and on `paste` should be enought.

Comment: Is `paste` is necessary here?

Comment: You to decide.... It makes your script check what is in the `textarea` when user is pasting something.